# DynamoDB sortkey mapping

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, mapping

I am using dynamoDB with java. DocumentI am using has three fields, which are defined as:

- Partition key (string)
- Sort key (string)
- body (json)

I am strugling with mapping sort key, it is plain string with pattern:

`X_YYYY_ZZZZZZ`

it has three values, joined with `_`, which corresponds to:

```java
class SortKey {
    private xValue;
    private yyyValue;
    private zzzzzzValue;
}
```

I defined field in document coresponding to sort key in DynamoDb like this:

```java
@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="yField")
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter=yFieldConverter.class)
private SortKey sortKey;
```

And wrote specific converter:

```java
public class SortKeyConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, SortKey> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final SortKey value) {
        return value.getVersionValue() + "_" + value.getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public SortKey unconvert(final String value) {
        String[] result = value.split("_");
        return SortKey(Version.createOf(result[0]), SomeFactory.create(result[1], result[2]));
    }
}
```

Problem is that storing in DynamoDB table is working, but when I try to load object from table I get:

`could not invoke public void com.Hierarchy.setHierarchySortKey(com.HierarchySortKey) on class com.Hierarchy with value YY_XXXX_ZZZZZZ of type class java.lang.String: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: could not invoke public void com.Hierarchy.setHierarchySortKey(com.HierarchySortKey) on class com.Hierarchy with value YY_XXXX_ZZZZZZ of type class java.lang.String at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$MethodReflect.set(StandardBeanProperties.java:136) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.set(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:111) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.createKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:295) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:448) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:85)`

I tried to change sortKey type to String leaving annotation on converter to see what will happen, if it is ignoring the converter annotation, and I have got :

`class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.SortKey (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.SortKey is in unnamed module of loader lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader @49097b5d): java.lang.ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.SortKey (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.SortKey is in unnamed module of loader lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader @49097b5d) at com.SortKeyConverter.convert(SortKeyConverter.java:8)t`

So it seems it knows about converte, but on load from table it does not work, I am running of ideas.

I am wondering if I am missing something, or I am trying to use library not as intended and the fact it works on store is coincidence and not intended feature.

Comment: You need to share yFieldConverter.class

Comment: @LeeHannigan I forgot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Migration to AWS SDK for Java version 2.x, solved the issue.